# Laravel REST API when to create separate controllers for list of values?

Tags: javascript, laravel, api, rest, vue.js

Let's say I have a simple API for registering a user. For each user I collect basic information such as: Name, email, state, gender, marital status. For state, gender and marital status I have a database table pre-populated with ids so I can present them in a dropdown and have the user select each.

Now when it comes to my API controller for registering users, should I be passing the list of values in a single JSON object?

```
return response()->json([
    'genderList' => Gender::get('id', 'name'),
    'stateList'  => State::get('id', 'abbr'),
    'maritalList => MaritalStatus::get('id', 'name')
]);
```

Or should I have a separate controller and API call for each of these that each return a single object?

Is there a proper way to do this or is it personal preference?

I'm using Vue as my frontend if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a personal preference as there is no `proper way` of doing it.
Keep in mind the number of network calls that will be passed and the number of hits on your database.

Personally, I prefer outputting an array using the `pluck()` method:

```
return response()->json([
    'genderList' => Gender::pluck('name', 'id'),
    'stateList'  => State::pluck('abbr', 'id'),
    'maritalList => MaritalStatus::pluck('name', 'id')
]);
```

It would be good as well to Cache those results as they may not change this often